# NodeJS + Socket.IO can't get json to return

Tags: node.js, angularjs, socket.io

I'm using Socket.IO, AngularJS, Request, and Express and I am trying to pull in some data from a request and then send it off to the client. Here are my functions:

```
    var getJsonFromJsonP = function (url, callback) {
        request(url, function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                var jsonpData = body;
                var json;
                try {
                   json = JSON.parse(jsonpData);
                }
                catch(e) {
                    var startPos = jsonpData.indexOf('({');
                    var endPos = jsonpData.indexOf('})');
                    var jsonString = jsonpData.substring(startPos+1, endPos+1);
                    json = JSON.parse(jsonString);
                }
                callback(null, json);
            } else {
                callback(error);
            }
        })
    }

    var getScoring = function() {
        var url = 'http://live.nhle.com/GameData/RegularSeasonScoreboardv3.jsonp';
        var dataReturn;
        getJsonFromJsonP(url, function (err, data) {
            console.log(data);
            return data;
        });
    }

    io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
        socket.emit('init', { data: getScoring() });
    });
```

The `getJsonFromJsonP` solution is from another post, and it is producing ok results.

The `console.log(data)` shows the correct data in the backend, but the client (AngularJS) is not getting it. If I change `return data` to  `return 'hello world'` the 'hello world' appears in the client as `{ data : 'hello world' }`.

Comment: what does `return JSON.stringify(data);` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getScoring()` function uses the `getJsonFromJsonP()`, which is asynchronous (as it has to wait for the request).

So you might also want to pass `getScoring()` a callback function, then emit the event in that callback. Like this for example:

```
var getScoring = function(callback) {
    var url = 'http://live.nhle.com/GameData/RegularSeasonScoreboardv3.jsonp';
    var dataReturn;
    getJsonFromJsonP(url, function (err, data) {
        //pass data to callback function
        callback(data);
    });
}

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    getScoring( function(data){
        socket.emit('init', { data: data });
    });
});
```

otherwise you won't be able to return anything because you are already out of the scope when  you have the data. You can log it to the console, but not return it.

Comment: This solution worked, thanks. I thought because the `console.log` was coming up with data, I didn't need to use another callback.